# Adding picture to moving 3D Viewport environment

Tags: image

I'm very new to blender so just trying to find my way around. I'm looking to be able to add a .png image to a moving 3D environment. I've run a short video sequence (which consists of a walk down a short corridor then turning a corner into another room) through Voodoo Camera Tracker Program then opened the sequence and python tracker script in Blender. I can now play the sequence and see the camera move through the corridor and view the trackers move with the tracking points. My goal is to be able to add a 2D .png image of someone sitting on a chair at the end of the sequence. I've got so far as importing the image as a plane and I've moved the plane to the coordinates on the chair however when I play the sequence and view through the viewport I cannot see the image that I've uploaded.

Sorry I know my lingo must sound very basic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a camera image to view the video in the background.

[image]

The camera image will show on camera view. Note that this image is for reference only and will not render.

To make the image renderable, just add it as background on the compositor.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you kindly susu.